# Dropdown menu is always showing in Themify theme (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

[Dropdown menu error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqz3o.jpg)

I have a blog with Themify theme. I updated Themify and now the sub menus are displayed all time (as you can see in the pic above).

Any ideas how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to add more information, a screenshot isn't enough to go off of. Do you have any code you can post?

Comment: Don't know what code post because i didn't modify anything :( I onlye updated the theme.

Comment: You will need to contact the creator of the theme for support. There are a ton of reason why you are seeing the issue you mentioned, but without some code, your guess is as good as ours.